# Duda Matrices & Array´s Multidimensionales JAVA

Tags: java, array, eclipse

tengo una duda sobre un método. Yo tengo una matriz con varias filas y columnas, la idea del método es que devuelva la fila de la matriz cuya media de sus elementos es mayor, el problema es que al probar el metodo me saca este error: [I@15db9742
El código es el siguiente: (Soy nuevo y nose aun como usar StackOverflow, disculpad las molestias de antemano)

```
private int [] [] ar1;

Matriz1(int NF, int NC)
{
    ar1 = new int [NF] [NC];    
}

void cargarPorFilas()
{
    for(int i=0; i<ar1.length ; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<ar1[i].length; j++)
        {
            System.out.print("Introduzca número: ");
            ar1 [i] [j] = Consola.leeInt();
        }
    }
}

void ver()
{
    for(int i=0; i<ar1.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<ar1[i].length; j++)
        {
           System.out.print(ar1 [i] [j]);
           System.out.print("\t");
        }
         System.out.println();
     }
 }

public int [] mayorFila()
{
    float media;
    int maxima = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int [] maxfila = new int [ar1.length];

    for(int i=0; i<ar1.length; i++)
    {
        float suma=0;
        for(int j=0; j<ar1.length; j++)
        {
            suma+=ar1 [i] [j];
        }
        media = suma / ar1.length;

        if(maxima<media)
        {
            maxima =  (int) media;              
            for(int j=0; j<ar1[i].length; j++)
            {
                maxfila [j] = ar1 [i] [j];  
            }   
        }
    }
    return maxfila; 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Matriz1 m1 = new Matriz1();
    m1.cargarPorFilas();
    System.out.println(m1.mayorFila());
}
```

Comment: `[I@15db9742` no es un error, es lo que devuelve el método `toString()` de un array de `int`, y sale de algún `System.out.print` que estés haciendo.

Answer (score 0):

También soy nuevo por aquí. Creo que te salta esa dirección de memoria debido a que le estás pidiendo que imprima en pantalla un vector forzosamente a partir del método mayoFila(), por lo que es normal que salga esto ya que no te saldrán todos los elementos del vector con un print.

```
    int[] v = new int[NC];
    v = mayorFila();
    System.out.print("La mayor fila con cuyo resultado es: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < NC; ++i)
    {
        System.out.print(v[i]+" ");
    }
```

Para ello crearía un nuevo vector y que se almacene el resultado de mayorFila(), ya con eso imprimes el resultado con un bucle cualquiera.

Un saludo.

EDIT: Me lo he planteado como lo haría con C++, en Java como han comentado se podría hacer con toString en el mismo print.